# How to use TAB in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am using Robot Framework for test automation. I have a test case where when the user enters an email address and presses <kbd>TAB</kbd> only, and then the next field, NAME, is enabled, otherwise it is disabled. How can I automate this?

Comment: Why must you hit tab for? cant you just input the text to the field ? Like normal?

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Right - Well if you need tab - use this. `press key | <locator...> | \\09`. If you then want to hit Enter key - replace the `\\09` with `\\13`. Read more about it here http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Press%20Key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) library for pressing any key from keyboard.

After installing, try the below lines for tab:

Keydown. tab

Keyup  tab

Comment: What do you mean by *"pressing any keyboard"*? Do you mean *"pressing any key"*? Or something else? (Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57414649/edit), not here in comments (as appropriate).)

Comment: Yeah , we can press any key from the keyboard

Answer (score 3):

Using Selenium2Library of Robot Framework, we can use the *[Press Keys](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Keys)* keyword. It's very easy and has support for a lot of keys including the "command" button for MAC.

```
Press Keys    locator    TAB
```

For all supported keys and their names, go to [Selenium keys](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.keys.html).

Comment: How does this work with the current 2019 version of SeleniumLibrary, please? :)

Comment: Try like this  -    Press Keys        ${Locator}        \TAB

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use AutoItLibrary and use keyword Send {TAB}.

Comment: What is "AutoItLibrary"? Some interface to [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt)?

Answer (score 1):

From the Selenium2Library documentation:

You can use the *Press Key* keyword.

[Press Key Example](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/horizontal-tab-ascii-code-9.html)

In your case you need to use:

Press Key   login_button    \09    # ASCII code for TAB key

[ASCII code chart](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/horizontal-tab-ascii-code-9.html)

Comment: The first link is incorrect - it does not link to a Press Key example. It is the same as the second link (ASCII code chart).

Comment: (SeleniumLibrary has both *[Press Key](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Key)* and *[Press Keys](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Keys)*.)

Comment: For *Press Key*: [*"DEPRECATED in SeleniumLibrary 4.0. use Press Keys instead."*](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Keys)

Answer (score 0):

Example from me would be from the SeleniumLibrary keyword Press Keys:

```
Press Keys  None  TAB
```

You don't have to use a locator, so in this case the locator=None. In this case it will just send a TAB to your screen.